# Experienced sound designer needed for evaluating uni project

Tags: evaluation, university

Hello everyone,

I am looking for an experienced sound designer for helping me in evaluating my final uni project. It would take no more than one hour to meet up on Skype and talk about the sound I have created for a short dramatic film.

I will be grateful for your help.

Happy Easter!

Answer (score 1):

hey there.

i'll give it a go if you're still up for it...

mail me at daniel@dcbelle.se

greets.
/danny

Answer (score 0):

Dear Danny, thank you for your response. I will email you shortly.
Best